# Filtering a list with 2 dropdowns in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have list on my Blazor form that can be filtered by Dealership via a dropdown item as such:

```
    <MudSelect T="string" Value="selectedDealer" Label="Select Dealership" Variant="Variant.Filled" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" >
            @foreach (var item in dealership) {
                <MudSelectItem  Value="@item.Id">@item.Dealership</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    <MudTable Items="FilteredDealer" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh>Dealership</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Brand</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Model</MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Nr">@context.Dealership</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Sign">@context.Brand</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Model</MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
    </MudTable>
@code{
 private string selectedDealer;
  private List<CarViewModel> car= new List<CarViewModel>();
  private List<CarViewModel> FilteredDealer => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedDealer)
        ? car.Where(s => s.Dealership== selectedDealer).ToList()
        : car;
}
```

I have created another dropdown that I want to use to have the use filter by Brand once they have filtered the list by Dealership:

```
 <MudSelect T="string" Value="selectedBrand" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled" >
            @foreach (var items in car) {
                <MudSelectItem  Value="@items.Brand">@items.Brand</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
@code{

   private string selectedBrand;
  private List<CarViewModel> FilteredBrand => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBrand)
        ? car.Where(s => s.Brand== selectedBrand).ToList()
        : car;
}
```

Currently, the dropdown just pulls the entire list of Brands, for each model, so I have a ton of duplicates instead of single Brands. Could someone guide me as to what I should be doing? I am new to the framework and not sure where to go with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a list of brands

```cs
 <MudSelect T="string" Value="selectedBrand" Label="Select Brand" Variant="Variant.Filled" >
            @foreach (var items in Brands) {
                <MudSelectItem  Value="@items">@items</MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
@code{

   private string selectedBrand;
   private List<CarViewModel> FilteredBrand => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedBrand)
        ? car.Where(s => s.Brand== selectedBrand).ToList()
        : car;
   //You have to initialize car
   private List<string> Brands => car.Select(x=>x.Brands).Distinct().ToList();
}
```